# Expression: (L "String is not null terminated" & & 0)

Tags: c, mailslot

I am fiddling around with mailslots and now I've run into a problem.
Whenever I try to run, I get the error message in the title, but I don't know how I should go about fixing it.
What I am trying to do is "fixing" the full path of the mailslot, but it seems to not like the strcat_s-part.

```
HANDLE mailslotCreate (char *name) {
    char fullName[50] = "\\\\.\\mailslot\\";
    strcat_s(fullName, strlen(fullName), name);
    return CreateMailslot(fullName, 0, TIME_OUT, NULL);
}
```

[Imgur link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lntAA.png)

EDIT: Changing the strlen to sizeof merely changed the error to "Buffer size too small" instead.

Comment: Check the manual for what the second argument of strcat_s means.

Comment: "Buffer size too small" probably means exactly what it says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation on [strcat_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx). It says that second parameter should be the size of destination buffer. As you pass `strlen(fullName)`, there is no room for terminating `\0`.

Change it to be `sizeof(fullName)` and your error should disappear.

Comment: Tried sizeof instead, now I get a "buffer is too small"-error of similair nature instead.

Comment: So... is `fullName` large enough?

Comment: You might want to print `strlen(name)` and verify that `strlen(name) + 14 < 50`

Comment: fullName should indeed be large enough, considering name consist of only 5 characters right now. That fixed it, it seems.